# Save best genome in a parallel NEAT-Python

Tags: python, neat

What title says. I can't figure out how to pick the genome with best fitness in NEAT-Python and save it to a file, only when one hits the fitness goal in the config.

For the goal winner, I'm using a common tutorial code :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pe = neat.ParallelEvaluator(20, eval_genomes)
    winner = p.run(pe.evaluate, 20)
    with open('winner.pk1', 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(winner, output, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

look  at this.. if you can try

```
with open("Winner.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(winner, f)
    f.close()
```